# y-axis not showing for LogLogPlot and LogLinearPlot even if Axes->{True,True} is set

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

This must be something trivial but I am having a hard time figuring out why it isn't working. I plot:

`LogLogPlot[{1,4,5},{x,10^(-3),10},Axes->{True,True}]` and get no y-axis (as in the following picture):
[image: pic1]

I get the same thing if I plot `LogLinearPlot[{1,4,5},{x,10^(-3),10},Axes->{True,True}]`, but I get the y-axis to appear if I plot `LogPlot[{1,4,5},{x,10^(-3),10},Axes->{True,True}]`. I am not sure why this is happening or how to rectify this.

Thanks.

Comment: it works OK for me on V12.1 screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u2NgD.png)

Comment: Mine is 11.1.1.0. I can't update, as it's managed by the university. Is this a bug then?

Comment: `Is this a bug then` it looks like it and it must have been fixed, I would not know for sure. You could always try V 12.1 online for free.

Comment: @Bill Yes, I fixed this when I tried it. I assumed it was a cut/paste thing. Why? Because otherwise it gives error and no plot at all if using `{-3}` instead of `(-3)`

Comment: @Bill Woops. I meant `()` (that's how I have it in my code). Not `{}`. I fixed the question.

Comment: Looks like it got fixed in 11.2. For 11.1.1, adding `AxesOrigin -> {0.001, 1}` as an option works for me.

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, you are right. I just checked. That works for me too! It works even if `Axes->{True,True}` isn't there. I'll use this for now then...Thanks.